# Should the clip region be explicitly set after invalidate(l,t,r,b)?

Tags: java, android, ondraw, clip, invalidation

The documentation out there seems to indicate that if you invalidate several regions of a `View` (using `invalidate(l,t,r,b)`) there is no need to specify those regions using clip region in the `onDraw()` method.

On the other hand, I've seen many examples of custom views, that maintain a dirty region in parallel to invalidating the region, and then use the dirty region to clip the canvas in the `onDraw()` method (See for example, [the `KeyBoardView` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java#KeyboardView.onBufferDraw%28%29))

Is the documentation incomplete on this issue? Should `invalidate()` and `clipRect()` be used hand in hand?

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to use invalidate() at the same time as clipRect().  There are times when you can use them independently, and times when you can use them together.

Being a method on View, invalidate() works at the level of the entire View. Invalidating a region like this causes Android to redraw just the region that has been invalidated, so you push fewer pixels as a result of a change.

Being a method on Canvas, clipRect() changes the effective drawing space for the subsequent draw operations on that Canvas.  This allows you to perform draw operations without having to adjust computations to only affect that limited space.  The Canvas will ensure that if you draw outside that space, it will have no effect.  You can also accumulate clip regions to create non-rectangular clip regions.

A Canvas does not have to be associated with a View.  Many times you simply want to draw into a Bitmap for later use.  So using clipRect() on a Canvas may or may not have anything to do with a View, and even then, may or may not have anything to do with an invalidation on that view.  If you want to use the two together as an optimization for very large drawing spaces, you will have to make sure that the invalidated region of the View is equivalent to the clipped region of the Canvas, which is not always straightforward given that clip regions are not always simple rectangles.

Comment: The Canvas part is clear to me. The invalidate explanation not so much. You say `invalidate(...)` causes android to redraw just a region. How is it done? How can I know, from within `onDraw()` what are the invalidated regions to draw? Or should I code to draw the whole view and android will just draw the invalidated regions? (which sounds very much like `clipRect()`)